# Display text value from dropdown form stored as integer

Tags: ruby, select, multidimensional-array, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Following [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease), I am creating a dropdown in form like this:

```
[['Lisbon', 1], ['Madrid', 2], ...]
```

which produces a dropdown list like:

```
<option value="1">Lisbon</option>
<option value="2">Madrid</option>
```

On my show page, I would like to display the text (`Madrid`) of my stored value instead of the integer (`2`).

The value is stored in the database. This is a live system, which means I cannot change the stored contents (I can, but prefer not to).

I prefer to build the dropdown list from a hash, but since this is the suggested format in RailsGuide, I assume there is a inbuilt helper that can do this. It would be easier if I store the dropdown list as a string, although it will take up a lot of spaces in the database.

I cannot use index since value does not start from`0`, and it might not be in order. I can write a search on this 2 dimensional array, but is there any easier way? Does anyone know the simplest way to solve this?

Comment: Following code works for me `<%= select_tag :city, options_for_select([['Lisbon', 1], ['Madrid', 2]]) %>`

Comment: What I want is in the view page, display the string "Madrid" when 2 is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations like this, where you have a selection with a direct mapping from a database value to a display value, and you consistently want to use the display value for presentation, I use this approach:

In your model, declare an array with the mapping relationship:

```
class Person

  GENDER = [
    ["Male", "m"],
    ["Female", "f"]
  ]

end
```

In your edit view (the form), you can create the select using this approach:

```
<%= f.select :gender, Person::GENDER %>
```

In the show view, you can display using this format:

```
<%= Person::GENDER.find {|item| item[1] == @person.gender }[0] %>
```

This approach gives you the ability to control the display order of items in the select, and still be able to render the display value reasonably easily.

Comment: ok... that's simple. Although I thought Rails would have a helper doing this. Thank you!

Comment: If they do, I haven't found it.  But then again, I worked this out years back and haven't seen a better alternative since.  Enjoy!